# LLVM create function with type "Instruction*"

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to use `Function::Create` method to create a function whose input parameter type is `llvm::Instruction*` but I didn't find any direct method in `class Type` to do that. Can anyone give me some hints?

Also For a concrete compare `Instruction *pi`, I tried `pi->getType()->print(errs())` and it returned me `i1` as type. But when I wrote a function `int externalCall(Instruction *p)` in another cpp file and compiled into IR. This IR says the type is `class.llvm::Instruction`. Why this two are different and how can I get the latter one from the API?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you would expect the IR to look like at the end, and how you would expect a call to that function to look like in the IR?

Comment: something like `call void @foo('class.llvm::Instruction' p)`

Comment: As far as the LLVM bitcode is concerned there's nothing special about `llvm::Instruction`, it's just a C++ type. So this question might be just as well about any other type. In particular, you would definitely not find any special treatment of that type. So I suggest searching for general ways to create a type in LLVM.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use c-style linking, the pointer type is largely irrelevant:

- cast to pointer to i8 on the llvm side
- receive whatever type you want on the c/c++ callee side.  `Instruction *` is ok

(Just use a `BitcastInst` to case, on the llvm side, like:

```
BitCastInst *bitcast = new BitCastInst(value, PointerType::get(IntegerType::get(context, 8), 0));
```

(... where `value` is your `Instruction *` object)